# Segmentation fault in a word counter

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The program separates a file and prints the words one by one, but when I compile and run it, it said segmentation fault.

Part of `main`:

```
char * w;
int Counter = 0;
while ( (w = nextword(fd)) != NULL) {
  printf("%d: %s\n", Counter, w);
  Counter++;
}
printf("words total = %d\n", Counter);
```

function `nextword`:

```
char * nextword(FILE * fd) {
int c;
int i;
c = fgetc(fd);
while (c != -1 ) {
    while  ( (c != ' ') && ( c != '\n')) {
        word[wordLength] = c;
        wordLength++;
    }
    return word;
    wordLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `wordLength` declared? And what's its value?

Answer (score 1):

This is what causes the problem:

```
return word;
wordLength = 0;
```

Once you return, the `wordLength = 0;` statement is never reached.

Move it to the top of your function to fix your implementation.

A better implementation would use a temporary buffer, rather than a global one. For example, you can do this:

```
size_t nextword(FILE * fd, char buf[], size_t max_len) {
    size_t len = 0;
    ... // Read data into buf up to max_len-1.
        // Then add null terminator, and return length.
        // When you return length of zero, it means the end of input
    return len;
}
```

The caller would call your function like this:

```
char w[100];
while ( nextword(fd, w, 100) != 0) {
  printf("%d: %s\n", Counter, w);
  Counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
 return word;
```

after

```
 wordLength=0;
```

My guess is that you never reset your wordLength and you end up having wordLenght very high.

Also please note that it's not a good practice to use global buffers / counters.

Comment: I've tried to put  wordLength=0; before the return statement but there still a segmentation fault ...